# Can SD card readers read a card which only implements the SPI mode?

Tags: microcontroller, spi, sd

I've read [How can I initialize/use SD cards with SPI?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/602105/how-can-i-initialize-use-sd-cards-with-spi).

If I connected a microcontroller's SPI slave pins to an SD card shaped connector, would this allow the microcontroller to appear as a very small SD card (given correct microcontroller code)?

- Are there pins which need to be pulled high or low for an SD card adapter to attempt an SPI connection?
- Or is the use of (real) SD cards' SPI mode limited to custom software on microcontrollers and not implemented in mainstream SD card readers?  i.e. Mainstream SD card readers will never attempt an SPI connection.

Comment: Did you read some of the docs provided at https://www.sdcard.org/downloads/pls/?